# Prototype design pattern, what is being cloned?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have been looking at the prototype pattern at this site:
http://www.newthinktank.com/2012/09/prototype-design-pattern-tutorial/

In sheep.java line 20 there is this piece of code:

```
    sheepObject = (Sheep) super.clone();
```

When you call super.close() aren't you copying the interface? What exactly is being cloned? I don't understand how the fields and methods of sheep are getting cloned.

```
// By making this class cloneable you are telling Java
// that it is ok to copy instances of this class
// These instance copies have different results when
// System.identityHashCode(System.identityHashCode(bike))
// is called 

public interface Animal extends Cloneable {

    public Animal makeCopy();

}
```

.

```
public class Sheep implements Animal {

    public Sheep(){

        System.out.println("Sheep is Made");

    }

    public Animal makeCopy() {

        System.out.println("Sheep is Being Made");

        Sheep sheepObject = null;

        try {

            // Calls the Animal super classes clone()
            // Then casts the results to Sheep

            sheepObject = (Sheep) super.clone();

        }

        // If Animal didn't extend Cloneable this error 
        // is thrown

        catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {

            System.out.println("The Sheep was Turned to Mush");

            e.printStackTrace();

         }

        return sheepObject;
    }

    public String toString(){

        return "Dolly is my Hero, Baaaaa";

    }

}
```

.

```
public class CloneFactory {

    // Receives any Animal, or Animal subclass and
    // makes a copy of it and stores it in its own
    // location in memory

    // CloneFactory has no idea what these objects are
    // except that they are subclasses of Animal

    public Animal getClone(Animal animalSample) {

        // Because of Polymorphism the Sheeps makeCopy()
        // is called here instead of Animals

        return animalSample.makeCopy();

    }

}
```

.

```
public class TestCloning {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        // Handles routing makeCopy method calls to the 
        // right subclasses of Animal

        CloneFactory animalMaker = new CloneFactory();

        // Creates a new Sheep instance

        Sheep sally = new Sheep();

        // Creates a clone of Sally and stores it in its own
        // memory location

        Sheep clonedSheep = (Sheep) animalMaker.getClone(sally);

        // These are exact copies of each other

        System.out.println(sally);

        System.out.println(clonedSheep);

        System.out.println("Sally HashCode: " + System.identityHashCode(System.identityHashCode(sally)));

        System.out.println("Clone HashCode: " + System.identityHashCode(System.identityHashCode(clonedSheep)));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to remember is that an interface cannot be instantiated, any instantiated object will be a class that implements the said interface.

**Animal animalSample** parameter is going to be of type Animal interface, but the object it points to will be of a class that implements the Animal interface, in this case **Sheep**.

So when you call the Animal.clone(), you are calling the clone method of the object that's implementing the interface (Sheep).

Answer (score 0):

It calls the super class clone method. In this case it looks like it's the clone method of the Object class.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone()